# Why can't I chain instantiations using the eponymous trick?

Tags: templates, d, currying

In D, when a template has a member with the same name as the template, any instantiation of the template refers directly to that member. But if that member is itself a template, I cannot immediately instantiate it for some reason. Creating an intermediate alias works, however.

```
template Foo(int x){
  template Foo(int y){
     enum int Foo = x+y;
  }
}
alias Foo1 = Foo!(1);
assert(Foo1!(2) == 3); // ok
int a = Foo!(1)!(1); // compile error Error: found '!' when expecting ')'
```

Why does this fail? Is there any way around this?

My goal is neatness and currying.

Comment: The immediate problem is that the parser doesn't support that sequence. But, is it just an oversight or not reasonable? I don't know but I do think the parser is working as the grammar designs; it isn't a bug, per se...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how *D* grammar is defined. Current compiler shows correct error message:

```
Error: multiple ! arguments are not allowed
```

Also this question is already filed as [Issue 1566](https://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1566) and from [issue comment 4](https://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1566#c4):

> If I don't miss something multiple `!` is considered harmful as `A!B!C` may be
>   considered as `A` instantiated with `B!C` or `A!B` instantiated with `C`. Also
>   requirement to always have parantheses in such case may be added but IMO it
>   doesn't look like a worthwhile language complication as it isn't generally
>   needed.

This can be workarounded by e.g. such `Inst` template:

```
template Foo(int x)
{ enum int Foo(int y) = x + y; }

alias Inst(alias Template, A...) = Template!A;

enum a = Inst!(Foo!1, 1);
```

Note *D* now has a new short template declaration syntax and also one doesn't need to use parantheses in case template argument is an identifier or a constant.